# How to work with get_posts with tax_query with taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am applying custom query by get_posts function with woocommerce product custom taxonomy. If I keep tax_query as only empty array it shows a valid result but when I write tax_query like below code it shows an empty array. 
I don't need WP_Query result I need get_posts result here.
Please help me if u know the solution.

```
 $args = array(
                    'post_type'        => 'product',
                    'numberposts'      => -1,
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'fields'           => 'ids',
                    'tax_query'      => array( array(
                            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
                            'field'           => 'slug',
                            'terms'           =>  array('blue'),
                            'operator'        => 'IN',
                        ) )
                );

            $filtered_posts = get_posts( $args );

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r( $filtered_posts );
            echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: This code works perfectly… so there is something else that is interacting with it, some other customizations, your theme a plugin.

Comment: I am using this code in plugin. and inside __construct function

Comment: It should not be used inside the constructor, but outside in a hooked function. You should better include all related code in your question and add more context explanations to your question.